LiDAR Visualization using react
I am very new to this LiDAR data, and I want to know why the data isn't showing up. I used .las file and converted it into .json file using phyton language using pdal method, then I tried to visualize the data at the webpage using this method
I tried converting the data from .las file into .json file
I tried to modify the x y z data and add some more
The result from the code I pasted
